# Cassandra, what is the efficient way to run subquery

Tags: cassandra, bigdata

I have a huge table of employees (around 20 to 30 million), and I have around 50,000 employee ids to select from this table.

What is the fastest way to query? Is it a query like this:

```
select * from employee_table where employeeid in (1,400,325 ....50000)
```

The ids are not necessarily in sequential order; they are in a random order.

Comment: Could you please give more information about question. if you have 5000 ids then you can select the data based on partition keys.

Answer (score 1):

When the IN clause is used in a query the load for the co-ordinator node increases because for every value (in your case the employee id) it needs to hit the required nodes (again based on the CL of your query) and collate the results before returning back to the client. Hence if your IN clause has a few values using IN is ok.
But in your case if you need to fetch ~50K employee IDs I would suggest you fire `select * from employee_table where employeeid = <your_employee_id>` in parallel for those 50K IDs
I would also suggest that when you do this you should monitor your cassandra cluster & to ensure these parallel queries are not causing a high load on your cluster. (This last statement is based on my personal experience :))